# How to convert rows into columns and filter using the ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
customer_id |  key_id.  |  quantity |
1           |    777    |    3      |
1           |    888    |    2      |
1           |    999    |    3      |
2           |    777    |    6      |
2           |    888    |    1      |
```

and I would like to use simple python or pandas to:

1. Make each unique customer id in a separate row
2. convert key_id to the columns titles and the values are the quantity

The output table should look like this:

```
            |  777    |  888  |   999  | 
1           |   3     |   2   |    3   |
2           |   6     |   1   |    0   |
```

I have been struggling to find a good data structure to do this but I couldn't. and using pandas I also couldn't filter using 2 ids. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pivot into `key_id` columns using [**`pivot_table()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```py
df.pivot_table(index='customer_id', columns='key_id', values='quantity').fillna(0)

# key_id       777  888  999
# customer_id               
# 1            3.0  2.0  3.0
# 2            6.0  1.0  0.0
```

---

To handle duplicates, `pivot_table()` averages them by default. To override this aggregation method, you can set the `aggfunc` param (`max`, `min`, `first`, `last`, `sum`, etc.):

```py
df.pivot_table(
    index='customer_id',
    columns='key_id',
    values='quantity',
    aggfunc='max',
).fillna(0)
```

Comment: I got this error: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: @codeDojo with the sample data or real data?

Comment: with the real data

Comment: @codeDojo try `pivot_table()` instead (answer updated)

Comment: Thank you. That is what I wanted to do. But all my quantity values are integers. However in the new df there are values like 3.5, 2.1, etc.. Where did the float come from?

Comment: Based on your original error, it seems you have some duplicate `customer_id`-`key_id` pairs. In that case `pivot_table()` averages the dupes for you. If you prefer a different aggregation method, you can set the `aggfunc` param.

Comment: In the sample data, the reason it turns to float is because some values are initially `nan` before we `fillna()`, so it all gets converted to `float` first.

Comment: Thank you so much. Last question. Is there a way that I do not include the duplicates? so it just overwrite instead of averaging them? Many thanks

Comment: @codeDojo no problem, check the updated answer. you can change the aggregation method using `aggfunc`, so you just have to decide whether you want the `max`, `min`, `first`, `last`, etc.